# C program showing a square instead of string

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I have done a lot with Java but I am currently trying to learn c. I am trying to make a program to convert a number from decimal to binary.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 33

int main( int argc, char*argv[ ] )

{
 unsigned int number, base, remainder, x, i;
 char result[LENGTH];

 puts( "Enter a decimal value, and a desired base: " );
 scanf( " %u", &number );
 scanf( " %u", &base );

 x = number;

 for( i=0; i < LENGTH; i++ )
 {
  remainder = x % base;
  x = x/base;
  result[i] = remainder;
 }

 printf( "%u equals  %s  (base-%u) \n", number, result, base );    

 //***result is probably backwards...


 return 0;



}
```

And here is what I get when I run it:

```
Enter a decimal value, and a desired base: 
5 2
5 equals    (base-2)
```

What is the square and how to I get it to display as a string (char array)?

Comment: If the value is above 127 (ASCII) that character will show up as a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Last Edit:** Your program might look like the following:

```
 unsigned int number, base, remainder, x, i;
 char result[LENGTH+1] = {0};

 puts( "Enter a decimal value, and a desired base: " );
 scanf( " %u", &number );
 scanf( " %u", &base );

 x = number;

 for( i=0; i < LENGTH; i++ )

 {
  // if base > 10, use alphabet!
  result[i] = remainder > 9 ? (remainder-10) + 'A' : remainder + '0';
  x = x/base;
  result[i] = remainder + '0';
 }
```

---

First, when writing the remainder, you should add the ASCII offset of the digit.

```
  result[i] = remainder + '0';
```

Also, you forgot to add`'\0'` at the end.

```
 result[i] = 0;
 printf( "%u equals  %s  (base-%u) \n", number, result, base );
```

---

**EDIT:** When writing to a c-string, I usually initialize the string to zeros:

```
char result[LENGTH] = {0};
```

This way you don't need to write the `null character` at the end , it is written for you.

---

Thanks @mmyers for pointing out the overflow :)
I would declare the string to hold `LENGTH+1`:

```
char result[LENGTH+1] = {0};
```

Comment: Note this solution is unlikely to work properly for bases larger than 10, since in general 10 + '0' != 'a' (or 'A'). It certainly doesn't work in ASCII.

Comment: `result[i] = 0` is out-of-bounds since the loop just incremented i to LENGTH.

Comment: @AraK: Not really. Did you see Pillsy's answer?

Answer (score 4):

You want to store a digit as a character in `result[i]`, rather than the actual number that's the remainder. One way to do this, for bases up to (say) 16, is to index into an auxiliary array (which can be a string literal) that has the digits you want.

```
char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

/* stuff */

result[i] = digits[remainder];

/* more stuff */
```

Also, the other comments that are telling you to null terminate your string are entirely correct.

EDIT: Whichever route you go, you should ensure that the value input for `base` is greater than 0 and not greater than whatever maximum you wish to handle.

Comment: +1 the idea of digits array is really better than a ternary operator ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your string has values between 32 and 127 to be displayed on a terminal.

```
for( i=0; i < LENGTH; i++ )

 {
  remainder = x % base;
  x = x/base;
  result[i] = remainder;
 }
```

In this section you are putting small values into the array, so it won't show up as ASCII letters.

You may just want to have something like:
      result[i] = remainder + '0';

An easy way to see is to print out the ascii value of each part of the string and see what value is.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an academic exercise? If not many C compiler libraries include the [itoa()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) function that does exactly what you need. It is not defined by the ISO standard C library, but is commonly included in most compilers.